# Handle mouseclick events on custom DrawingVisual Object UIElement

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to add a drawingvisual object in canvas with MouseButtonEventHandler. But unable to get click event. What am i doing wrong here?

```
public class VisualHost : UIElement
    {

        public Visual myVisual { get; set; }

        public VisualHost()
        {
            Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            IsHitTestVisible = true;
            MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(MyVisualHost_MouseLeftButtonUp);
        }

        protected override int VisualChildrenCount
        {
            get { return myVisual != null ? 1 : 0; }
        }

        protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
        {
            return myVisual;
        }

       //mouse event
        private void MyVisualHost_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You clicked a drawing-Visual");

        }
    }


 private void AddMyVisualObject()
    {
        GeometryDrawing myRectDrawing = new GeometryDrawing(Brushes.Yellow, new Pen(Brushes.White, 1.5), new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0, 0, 200, 100)));
        DrawingVisual myDV = new DrawingVisual();
        DrawingContext myDC = myDV.RenderOpen();
        myDC.DrawDrawing(myRectDrawing);
        myDC.Close();
        VisualHost myVH = new VisualHost { myVisual = myDV };
        myDrawingCanvas.Children.Add(myVH);
    }
```

Please help required, How can I get the events to fire when clicking on a DrawingVisual?

Comment: You may want to take a look at [Hit Testing in the Visual Layer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/hit-testing-in-the-visual-layer). Is there any particular reason why you're dealing with DrawingVisuals instead of regular UI elements like Paths?

Comment: i am working on a timeline-grid where repeatedly 30 to 50 or more rectangles and more sub items has to be drawn for change of each date. so resulting in lot of rectangles on canvas

Comment: And you have encountered performance problems with using Rectangles or Paths?

Comment: ya delay in loading if sub items(sub rectangles) quantity are more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use a `VisualCollection` to host your `Visual` elements and in addition perform the hit testing for them by yourself:

```
public class VisualHost : FrameworkElement
{
  private VisualCollection Children { get; set; }

  public VisualHost()
  {
    this.Children = new VisualCollection(this);
    this.MouseLeftButtonUp += MyVisualHost_MouseLeftButtonUp;
  }

  public void AddChild(Visual visual)
  {
    this.Children.Add(visual);
  }

  protected override int VisualChildrenCount => this.Children.Count;

  protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index) => this.Children[index];

  //mouse event
  private void MyVisualHost_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
    // Initiate the hit test by setting up a hit test result callback method.
    VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(this, null, OnVisualClicked, new PointHitTestParameters(e.GetPosition((UIElement) sender)));
  }

  private HitTestResultBehavior OnVisualClicked(HitTestResult result)
  {
    if (result.VisualHit.GetType() == typeof(DrawingVisual))
    {
      MessageBox.Show("You clicked a DrawingVisual");   
    }

    // Stop the hit test enumeration of objects in the visual tree.
    return HitTestResultBehavior.Stop;
  }
}
```

Then initialize the host:

```
private void AddMyVisualObject()
{
  GeometryDrawing myRectDrawing = new GeometryDrawing(Brushes.Yellow, new Pen(Brushes.White, 1.5), new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0, 0, 200, 100)));
  DrawingVisual myDV = new DrawingVisual();
  DrawingContext myDC = myDV.RenderOpen();
  myDC.DrawDrawing(myRectDrawing);
  myDC.Close();

  VisualHost myVH = new VisualHost();
  myVH.AddChild(myDV);
  this.Canvas.Children.Add(myVH);
}
```

See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/using-drawingvisual-objects) for further information.

Comment: Good catch. Note that setting Visibility and IsHitTestVisible in the constructor is redundant.

Comment: Thats fantastic. I forgot to add it to Collection. Its working perfectly now. Thanks a lot fo quick solution

Comment: For reference: [Using DrawingVisual Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/using-drawingvisual-objects).

Comment: @Clemens Thank you. You are right. This properties are 'true' by default. (But  are required to be 'true'). I remove it. Since it is clear that an object that is not visible or not hittestable can't be clicked...